# unable to implement php with nginx

Tags: php, linux, nginx, fastcgi, archlinux

I have nginx working with arch linux.  I am having trouble adding php and fastcgi.  I installed the php and php-fpm packages.  php-fpm service is on.  When I access a file with a php extension, the browser displays the nginx error page and I get the following nginx error log message added:

> 2013/01/02 22:39:43 [error] 721#0: *27 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.13, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "192.168.1.19"

the contents of the php file seem to make no difference.  I have been unable to locate php error log or create my own.  I added the following to `/etc/php/php.ini`:

```
error_log = /var/log/php_error.log
```

and I made the file world writable but nothing goes there.  I added the following to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi.conf;
        }
```

uncommenting the commented lines changes nothing.  Commenting the uncommented lines changes the browser page displayed from error page to file not found page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running PHP *and* PHP-fpm?

Comment: php-fpm is installed and the service is active.  I installed the php package.  I am operating under the assumption that php does not need to be enabled or started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had to uncomment a line in the php-fpm.conf file to have fastcgi listen on the right port.

Comment: path of this file ?

Comment: which line you uncommented?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your configuration file to this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was unable to restart nginx after making the suggested modifications.  I got the following message:  nginx: [emerg] unknown "documant_root" variable

Comment: I guess slash is missing (/) $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name; or you can remove that line if not required.